# How do reference an object in a different namespace?

Tags: kubernetes

My Service is defined in a particular namespace, different to the namespace of my ingress controller. My ingress controller is defined in the default namespace. My services are defined in the app namespace. How do I spec in yaml that api-svc (see below) is in the app namespace?

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: api-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service: 
              name: api-svc
              port: 
                number: 8100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: api-ingress
  namespace: app
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service: 
              name: api-svc
              port: 
                number: 8100
```

You can apply your ingress config to the namespace in which `api-svc` **app** namespace. A single ingress controller in any namespace will be able to manage all the ingress objects or resources you create in the cluster.

**Ingress controller** watches the object **ingress** across the cluster, we just need to make sure we apply the **ingress** config in which **service** exists.

The **Ingress controller** uses the `kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx` to monitor the ingress resource.

If you have any chance and looking to manage all ingress in a single namespace, not in a different namespace you can use the **ExternalName** service.

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: svc-app
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: SvcName.Namespace.svc.cluster.local
  ports:
  - port: 8100 
    targetPort: 8100
```

Your ingress will be something like this then in the **Default** namespace

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
  name: api-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /api
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service: 
              name: svc-app
              port: 
                number: 8100
```